# Capelli identities and  D.A. Buchsbaum's "Resolution of Weyl modules: the Rota touch" 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, co.combinatorics

In ["Resolution of Weyl modules: the Rota touch"](http://books.google.de/books?id=eaJyGXguokIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=capelli%2520identity&f=false) pages 105 bottom, 106 top D.A. Buchsbaum 
mentions some identities which he call "Capelli identities".
Can one explain how it might be related to the standard [Capelli identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capelli%27s_identity)  ?
Or suggest some text where it is explained or some comment how it might be related ?